# display rows which contain "#Error" in query ouput

Tags: sql, join, ms-access-2007

I have a right join query (joining a table and another query output). I get "#Error" displayed in some rows. Is there a way to just display the rows which give "#Error" ?

Here is my query:

```
SELECT Table1.Number1, Table2.Number2
FROM Table2 RIGHT JOIN Table1 ON Table2.Number2 = Table1.Number1;
```

Sample Data:

```
Expr1   Expr2
2346    2346
2347    2347
2348    #Error
2349    2349
2350    2350
2351    2351
```

Sub Query:

```
SELECT Val(Right([String2],Len([String2])-8)) AS Number2
FROM Table3;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show some of the data that results in #Error.

Comment: @rontornambe updated with sample data

Comment: How about showing us the sub-query too?

Comment: @rontornambe updated with sub query

Comment: Looks to me like the #Error is occurring because your subquery is  performing two operations that occasionally fail.  The "Right" could fail if the string is 8 or fewer characters in length.  The "Val" could fail if the substring isn't numeric.  If you want to see just #Error rows, then query for items that would cause either of those conditions. If you don't want Errors, then do an INNER JOIN instead.

Comment: Although Griffen's surmises are probably correct, it is always a good idea to provide us with all relevant information. What data values does String2 take? If you desk-check these values, your answer will likely become apparent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a WHERE clause on the end.  Should work fine.  If you have multiple columns that the #ERROR rows might show up in, use a WHERE clause with ORs (or, alternately, ||s ) in it.  If you toss out a clearer idea of which columns have #ERRORs in them, I could batch you together a code block for it, but it should be pretty easy for you to handle for yourself.

Edit: Correction:

```
SELECT Table1.Number1
FROM Table1
WHERE Table1.Number1 NOT IN (
    SELECT Table2.Number2 FROM Table2
)
```

You're getting errors because you're forcing table1 to show up even where there's nothing in table 2 to match it.  This will give you the orphans.

Comment: how would that fix the #Error?

Comment: He didn't ask to fix the things.  He asked to display them.  Why do you downvote me for answering the question the OP asked?

Comment: This answer is not useful. What would the asker need in their where clause? Just as with questions, answers need to have a certain amount of specificity.

Comment: Given the user's question, I had assumed that the #ERROR was showing up in specific columns.  What would be the point of displaying just a list of identical rows?  Given that I didn't have the columns to work with, I couldn't write up the WHERE clause myself, could I?

Comment: @BenBarden I didn't do the downvote, I just commented on your original answer.

Comment: Thank you, user793468.  I, in turn, have edited my answer based on that.  I hope you find it helpful.